How to prevent the use of mismatch header files and library?
I provide a library with its header files to a user.
I often release new versions, minors and majors.
Sometimes the user still uses an old version of the header files and somehow he still can link the shared library against it.
Changes are made internally and on the API but on things he doesn't seem to use, therefore I believe the linker still thinks it's valid.
How can I version so that I'm 100% sure the user will use the correct header files with the library?
I'm not 100% sure the problem is this one, but it's just a question.

There's no way to enforce tight coupling between a library and its header files. Other than to make sure the installation of the library also overwrites the existing header files.

If you insist, define a version variable in both the header and library, then check at runtime that they match. However, users can break things in all kinds of ways with a bad install, guarding against this very specific scenario seems to be very unfruitful.

thanks! I thought it'd have been easier to prevent lacking knowledge users from doing crap.

In theory, you could #define a macro with a version number, attach that to some (or all) class names, and typedef the versioned class name back to the general name. That way, even when users type in the general name, they are actually using the versioned one (which, unfortunately, will also show in compiler errors), so when they link with a library that was compiled with a different version, all those names will not match.

The obvious way is to distribute updates of the library and the header file using an installer, and the installer (when download and run) takes care of updating both in sync.  Avoid distributing the header files and libraries separately (e.g. as distinct files on a server that must both be manually downloaded by the end user and placed in correct locations) - relying on an end user to download multiple files that must be kept in sync is a recipe for getting those files out of sync.

That's what I provide but he copies the headers into his own app and he even changes my files... I'm tired of educating him and replying to his support requests then I want to prevent any misuse. He has 7+yrs of xp in C++ and linked my shared library as a static library.. I was surprised g++ doesn't complain.

@ChristianStieber A bit overkill but that's actually a solution. Thanks!

As to a user who willfully changes your files - not much you can do about that.   Simply tell him formally (say, with an appropriate letter - or, even better, when renegotiating a support contract) that, since he has history of modifying your header files or library,  you no longer will provide him with technical support.   The justification is that you have no control over his modifications, and no means to sensibly provide advice (or, to estimate the cost effort required to provide advice) when his (undisclosed?) edits have changed functionality of your library.

The short response is, you can't.
But, with some awareness it can be done. Take a look ad SOLID principle, it is the way to create a stable API, which gives you sufficient flexibility to modify your application, at the same time not breaking the binary backward compatibility and disturbing others.

Try to separate the headers, the ones which should be used externally, and and the ones are meant to be used internally. Make a clear separation and decouple them explicitly.
You might probably notice that headers to be used by externally probably change much more rarely than internal ones, which should seem quite normal. If this is not the case, then you have things to reconsider there.
Spot what are changes external headers and try to make make a policy to not change them, under random circumstances. It is a good exercise to understand better the design of your application.
Ok, very big changes will come with changes to external headers anyway, so changing these must not be done under any random circumstances. It should be done in centralized way exclusively.
If changes to external headers come as often as the ones to internal headers, then you should stop there and seriously reconsider the architecture of your application. After you do it, then follow normally the enumerated above.

What you should expose? I would recommend to expose functions and interfaces only. Everything else comes with the risk of breaking the binary backward compatibility. Expose only the functions and interfaces required by that particular client. The client should not be aware of your internal changes, or of changes for other clients. In this case externals will be changed usually rarely, but if changed, it will lead to compile errors and users will be forced to fix them.
If you want to expose structures and classes, then you got a problem there. Make a clear policy to not expose structures and classes. It still might be not an option, so make a clear policy of not changing them on random circumstances. These changes will cost you too much. But if still you require to change them, first of all rethink carefully the architecture then perform these changes in a centralized way.

It is actually very easy.
namespace mylibrary_v1_17 {
  // all your definitions go here
}

namespace mylibrary = mylibrary_v1_17;

You make an incompatible change to the library, you bump a version number, and you are done. End users only use namespace mylibrary so they don't notice any changes.
Whether you want to do this is a different question. One should generally aim for backwards compatibility. Don't remove old APIs, but rewrite them in terms of new APIs.

Better than the #define solution in comment (but is valid with C too). I believe I can even easily integrate it with PImpl. Thanks!

I definately agree regarding backwards compatibility when changing a minor version. For major version - using such namespaces is a good idea IMHO (at least when backwards compatibility is less feasible).

Note that (in comments below the question) the OP has mentioned an end user who willfully modifies the OPs files - including, presumably, the header file.   Your approach, while fine as it is, does not provide a counter-measure to the willful end user - you are implicitly trusting in the end user not to willfully make edits that circumvent your protections.
